# Do I meet stimulus check eligibility standards?

Tags: united-states, retirement, irs, covid-19, stimulus

My last year to file an income tax form was 2017, as my CPA informed I no longer made enough (retired) to make filing necessary. My only income now is my monthly Social Security disability check for $943.00 and $100.00 per month from a part-time job.

Am I eligible for a stimulus check? How much? When?

Comment: I'd answered this, but upon further digging it looks like SSDI folks get automatic payments. https://time.com/5822700/stimulus-social-security-disability/ "That’s also true of people who receive Social Security, Railroad Retirement or Social Security Disability Insurance (SSDI), who will automatically receive stimulus payments even if they don’t typically file tax returns. “People in these groups are expected to see the automatic $1,200 payments later this month,” the IRS said in a statement."

Comment: many thanks/feeling more optimistic now

Comment: @ceejayoz Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Nosjack Because I can't find this distinction on the IRS website, and I've already answered incorrectly once. Hoping someone can find a more solid source.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will get the check. If your SSDI is direct deposited into your bank account you should get it before the end of April. If you get a paper check for the SSDI you may have to wait a bit longer.

@ceejayoz Gave the answer in a comment, but the official statement can be found [here on the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/economic-impact-payment-information-center).

> **Q2. Will I receive a Payment if I do not make enough money to normally have to file an income tax return?**
>
> A2.  Yes. Eligible retirees and recipients of Social Security
>   retirement, disability (SSDI), survivors benefits, Railroad
>   Retirement, or veterans benefits, as well as individuals who do not
>   make enough money to normally have to file a tax return, are also
>   eligible for the Payment. This includes those who have no income, as
>   well as those whose income comes entirely from federal benefit
>   programs, such as supplemental security income (SSI) benefits. No
>   minimum income is needed for the Payment.